# TI CC2541 sensortag firmware flashing

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am very new in TI CC 2541 sensor tag.

Can anyone help me how to flash new firmware into it??
I have IVR studio but I don't have CC debugger, 
Is it necessary to have CC debugger or any other way to flash it?

Things I have:
CC2541 sensor tag
IVR studio

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a [CC Debugger](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-debugger) in order to debug and/or flash firmware. After you have a working firmware you can flash it using the [SmartRF Flash Programmer](http://www.ti.com/tool/flash-programmer) version `1.12.7`. SmartRF Flash Programmer has a command line tool that you can integrate in your deployment process. Get a [CC2541 SensorTag](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2541dk-sensor) for initial development and prototyping.

Comment: Yes i have CC2541 SensorTag developement kit which has already working firmware...and also downloaded SmartRF flash Programmer.
But will this SmartRF flash programmner flash the firmware without having CC debugger???

Comment: You still need to have the CC Debugger for flashing with SmartRF.

Comment: Btw you also need IAR Embedded Workbench as an IDE. You cannot use IVR Studio for flashing purpose.